# Vcap Pin on STM8S003F3

Tags: st, stm8

I am using STM8S003F3P6 to drive a relay and control 4 LEDs using a switch. However, my programmer is not able to detect the chip and am not able to program it. I think it might have to do with the Vcap pin not connected, however in the datasheet or the user manual there are no instructions on how to connect this pin.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes the unconnected Vcap is most likely cause.

If you use the search functionality in PDF reader, you will find 11 mentions of Vcap, including information how to connect it properly.

Comment: I should have mentioned searching through PDF as a method to finding the answer too. But yeah, PDF and CLTRL+F are our bread and butter

Comment: Yes I did actually do that first but it said something about 1.8 V regulator so I figured that since there is no 1.8 V source, I ignored it. My bad. I am guessing I am supposed to ground it using a 1 uf / 2.2uf Cap?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, datasheet, page 49:

[image]

Second of all, what programmer are you using? I will assume it's ST-Link because it's the most common kind in my underexperienced opinion. Please, specify that so we're all on the same page.

It's likely the problem is only in VCAP. But without correcting VCAP saying anything else is impossible, because having it unconnected clearly violates general operating conditions. Only when VCAP is connected properly (for example, 1uF or 2.2uF external cap) and the problem remains, we can look further into the issue if it's not resolved.

Comment: Hi, yes I am using the ST-Link. It said in the datasheet something about 1.8V regulator, I assumed since there was no such voltage source, I don't need to add the Vcap. 

So I will add 1uf / 2.2uf external cap to Ground or 5V?

Comment: @Amorphous you add it as it is stated here. To the pin. The other side of the cap goes to the ground, as it always does. So a trace comes out of the pin and goes into the capacitor, that has another side to the ground. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, got it! :)

Comment: like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WmSJ.jpg